# wpf window throws exception when trying to show

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I created a WPF application and it runs perfectly on several computers.
There is one computer that keeps throwing an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception.
I can't install Visual Studio on that computer, but i found the line that causes the problem:

```
var m_GCSWindow = new GCSWindow();
m_GCSWindow.Show();
```

everything runs perfectly until the `Show()`.

i can't figure this one out because:

1. it works on all the other computers.
2. it's MVVM, no code behind.

what could be the problem?

**Edit:**
I was finally able to install visual studio on the problematic computer, and found that if i remove a single line from the XAML everything loads ok.

```
<Image Source="{Binding MapView.MapImage,Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" 
    Stretch="None" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown"
    ContextMenu="{StaticResource MapRightClick}" />
```

so i thought the problem might be in the converter, and put a break point in it, but the exception occurs before.

**Edit 2:**
After a little more investigation i found that `MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown"` is what causes the problem.
when i remove that line everything works.

```
private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (ImageClickCommand != null) ImageClickCommand.Execute(e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement));
}
```

that's the code, and i put a break point in it but still i never get there.
I even tried moving the event to another control, but i still have the same issue.

Comment: Look at the constructor of GCSWindow, I think problem is in it

Comment: Maybe .NET framework version is different on the PC that is causing problem, but this is nothing more than a guessing game. HTH

Comment: @Narek the constructor is empty, as i said - no code behind.

Comment: @XAMlMAX that was the first thing i checked.. same framework on all pcs. plus, this pc is identical to another pc that works normally.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before. The bug can probably be found in the converter

Try debugging the converter

Make sure it gets called
Make sure it gets the value that you want it to convert
Make sure it doesn't crash when converting
Make sure you get the value you want

Etc etc etc

Also - Can you post the code for ImageConverter?

Comment: turns out it's not the converter. if you still want the code here it is: [pastebin.com/7jG8JBD0](http://pastebin.com/7jG8JBD0)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe m_GCSWindow is null perhaps you could put in a null check .

Does GCSWindow reside in a DLL? Maybe the DLL is missing? Maybe one of its depdencies is missing.

You could also put a try catch around that call